# Nestjs can't resolve dependencies of XModel

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, module, nestjs

I have been working on this app for like 3 months which is near completion. But since yesterday I have been unable to solve this problem. I want to use activityTypeService in activityLogService and I have been getting this wired error. I have already exported activityTypeservice in its module. see below

below is ActivityTypeModule, I export ActivityTypeService so it can available in ActivityLogService

```
@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'ActivityType', schema: ActivityTypeSchema },])],
  providers: [ActivityTypeService,],
  controllers: [ActivityTypeController],
  exports: [ActivityTypeService,]
})
export class ActivityTypeModule { }
```

The code below is activityLog module and ActivityTypeModule is imported

```
@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'ActivityLog', schema: ActivityLogSchema }]), ActivityTypeModule],
  providers: [ActivityLogService, ActivityTypeModule],
  controllers: [ActivityLogController],
  exports: [MongooseModule,]
})
export class ActivityLogModule { }
```

so I use it the activityLogService as shown below

```
@Injectable()
export class ActivityLogService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('ActivityLog') private activitylogModel: Model<ActivityLog>,
        private activityTypeService: ActivityTypeService
    ) { }

    async activitylog(activityuser: string, activitytype: string, activitydetails: string, activitydate: Date) {
        const activitiesLog = {
            activityuser: activityuser,
            activitytype: activitytype,
            activitydetails: activitydetails,
            activitydate: activitydate
        }
        const activity = new this.activitylogModel(activitiesLog);
        console.log(activity);
        await activity.save()
    }
}
```

But I am still getting this wired error which I dont understand

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ActivityTypeService (?). Please make sure that the argument ActivityTypeModel at index [0] is available in the ActivityTypeService context.

Potential solutions:
- If ActivityTypeModel is a provider, is it part of the current ActivityTypeService?
- If ActivityTypeModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ActivityTypeService?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ActivityTypeModel */ ]
  })
```

Comment: Can you try to remove the `ActivityTypeModule` from the `providers` array of the `ActivityLogModule`?

Comment: Did that but having the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error, somewhere you have `ActivityTypeService` in an `imports` array somewhere, which shouldn't be happening. Along with that, I can see you have `ActivityTypeModule` in a `providers` array, which is also not supported, though Typescript doesn't have a good way to show errors about that, so you aren't seeing any errors.

In general, as Nest error like that is in the form of

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the <Provider> (?). Please make sure that the argument <injected_valued> at index [<index>] is available in the <module> context.
```

`<Provider>` and `<module>` should never be the same value, and if they are, it's a good indication that you have a provider in an imports array.