# Nestjs cannot resolve dependency index[0] when decorator is being used

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am new to NestJs and i have a question for you that i could not resolve it.

UsersService has two dependencies

-TypeOrm UsersRepository Injection
-WalletsService Injection

Typeorm injection is done by decorator as you see down below.

```js
//UsersService
@Injectable()
export class UsersService implements IUserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Users)
    private usersRepository: Repository<Users>,
    private readonly walletsService: WalletsService,
  ) { }
```

Whenever i changed first injection it cannot be resolved.

Probably i am missing something. There are all photos down below with description

```js
//UsersModule
@Module({
  controllers: [UsersController],
  exports: [UsersService],
  imports: [WalletsModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Users])],
  providers: [UsersService],
})

export class UsersModule { }
```

```js
//WalletsModule
@Module({
  controllers: [WalletsController],
  exports: [WalletsService],
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Wallets])],
  providers: [WalletsService]
})

export class WalletsModule { }
```

[When Users Repository is first injection]

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?, WalletsService). Please make sure that the argument UsersRepository at index [0] is available in the UsersService context.

Potential solutions:
- If UsersRepository is a provider, is it part of the current UsersService?
- If UsersRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UsersService?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing UsersRepository */ ]
  })
```

[When Wallets Service is first injection ]

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?, UsersRepository). Please make sure that the argument WalletsService at index [0] is available in the UsersService context.

Potential solutions:
- If WalletsService is a provider, is it part of the current UsersService?
- If WalletsService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UsersService?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing WalletsService */ ]
  })
```

Thank you in advance. I hope it is descriptive enough. Have good day!

Comment: Please do not post content that is clearly text as images. You could have copied the error messages as plain text instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nestjs can't resolve dependencies of XModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579054/nestjs-cant-resolve-dependencies-of-xmodel)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jay. I looked up the question you answered. As i understood right, import array should have only module and not provider. It is vice versa with provider array. As you see in question, in that perspective, my code is just like what  you suggested.

In UsersService constructor first parameter gives injection error, it is not dependent on WalletsService or TypeOrm generated Repository. Whenever i switch parameters the other gives the "cannot resolve" error :/

Thank you for your comment and help. I used your testing-nestjs repo a lot. Thanks ! - @JayMcDoniel

Comment: You are right! @JayMcDoniel. I looked up whole code base and found some errors which is the same with you pointed out. Probably one mistake triggered another. 

Thanks for helping !

Answer is yours and i do not know how to approve your comment as answer. If you know please help and i can close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity of the answer from the comments:

There was a service in an `imports` array which leads to problems with Nest trying to resolve things. In general, these errors can start to be debugged knowing that Nest's error is in the form of

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (<dependencies_with_unknown_as_?>. Please make sure that the argument <unknown_dependency> at index [] is available in the <related_module> context.